# Как заставить работать SMS Retriever API?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я начинающий Android разработчик и никак не могу разобрать с SMS Retriever API.
Крайне мало информации по данному вопросу. Нашел код реализации на Kotlin и Java, но что делать дальше и как заставить работать понять не могу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все реализовать или что дополнительно можно почитать? Главное на чем сейчас застрял это как получить номер телефона пользователя

```
private fun requestHint() {
    val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
            .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
            .build()

    val intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
            mCredentialsApiClient, hintRequest)

    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(intent.intentSender,
                RC_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Error In getting Message", e.message.toString())
    }

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RC_HINT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        /*You will receive user selected phone number here if selected and send it to the server for request the otp*/
        var credential: Credential = data!!.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)!!

    }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/gits-apps-insight/easy-ways-to-implement-automatic-sms-verification-in-android-2b5d8040afbd советую почитать данную статью, в свое время мне помогло.

Comment: Спасибо за статью, помогла в разрезе того какой вид должно иметь сообщение.
Но у меня проблема пока в том, что не выходит получить даже номер телефона пользователя, конкретно поле "mCredentialsApiClient" на которое ругается AS и я не могу понять, что с ним делать?

Comment: Извиняюсь за поздний ответ, скорее всего поле "mCredentialsApiClient" это что то наподобие mCredentialsApiClient = Credentials.getClient(this), вот ссылка на оф.документацию по этому поводу https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться дальше